# Consider the region $R$ bounded by $y=f(x)>0$, $x=1$, and $x=2$.

Tags: calculus, volume

Problem:
Consider the region $R$ bounded by $y=f(x)>0$, $x=1$, and $x=2$. If the volume of a solid formed by rotating $R$ about the $y$-axis is $\pi$, and the volume formed by rotating $R$ about the line $x=-3$ is $6\pi$, find the area of $R$.

I am not sure how to go about this using either the shell method or washer method.
Also, I am not familiar with the proper math tools on this site, I apologize for that.

Comment: do you know the formula to rotate f(x) around  x and y axes

Comment: @trula shell method: V = integral of A(y)dy over[c,d] & Washer method is V=integral of rhdx over[a,b]

Comment: are you still there ?

Comment: @Physor yes sorry

Comment: there is an answer for you

Comment: @Physor where did the 3 come from equation 2?

Comment: Is it not clear yet ?

Comment: @Physor ah, I got it now, thanks!

Comment: you're welcome!

Comment: could you consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works

For rotation about ($x = 0$)-axis
$$
V_{x=0} = \int_0^{2\pi}\left(\int_1^2 f(r)rdr\right)d\phi = 2\pi\int_1^2 f(r)rdr = \pi 
$$
That means
$$
\int_1^2 f(r)rdr = 1/2   \tag{*}
$$
For rotation about ($x = -3$)-axis
$$
V_{x=-3} = \int_0^{2\pi}\left(\int_4^5 f(r)rdr\right)d\phi = 2\pi\int_4^5 f(r-3)rdr = 6\pi 
$$
That is
$$
\int_4^5 f(r-3)rdr = 3 
$$
For the last integral change variables $r = x +3$ so it becomes
$$
3 = \int_4^5 f(r-3)rdr = \int_1^2 f(x)(x+3)dx = \int_1^2 f(x)xdx + 3\int_1^2 f(x)dx   
$$
the area $R$ is the $\int_1^2 f(x)dx$ and from Eq.($*$) you can get $\int_1^2 f(x)xdx$. Substitute these in the last equation you get
$$
3 = \frac{1}{2} + 3R \Rightarrow R = \frac{5}{6}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This problem is literally trivial when you use Pappus's ($2^{nd}$) Centroid Theorem: the volume of a planar area of revolution is the product of the area $A$ and the length of the path traced by its centroid $C$, i.e., $2\pi C$. The bottom line is that the volume is given simply by $V=2\pi CA$.

Thus,
$$
V_1=2\pi CA=\pi\\
V_2=2\pi (C+3)A=6\pi\\
C=\frac{1}{2A}\\
A=\frac{5}{6}
$$

where $C$ is the centroid of the area $A$ relative to $y=0$. Notice that there are no integrals and no reference to the function $f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it